# Dynamically add series to matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I making an application to plot Airfoils profiles in matplotlib and I need to plot a number of profiles in the same subplot. I know how to add a fixed number of series, but not how to do it dynamically. My code for one profile is:

```
pts = d['AG17']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.plot(pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1], '-r')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

and for example for two profiles something like

```
ax.plot(pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1], '-r', pts1[:, 0], pts1[:, 1], '-r')
```

but how do I do it for `n` numbers of profiles?

Comment: You can make several `plot` calls for a single subplot.

Comment: If you are making _many_ `LineCollection` might also be useful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the `ax.plot` calls in a for loop:

```
profiles = ['AG17','AG18','AG19', ... , etc.] # I'm guessing at your profile names!
linestyles = ['r-','b--','g:', ..., etc.] # Use this if you want different colors or linestyles for each profile

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

for prof, ls in zip(profiles,linestyles):
    pts = d[prof]
    ax.plot(pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1], ls)

ax.grid()
plt.show()
```